# how to run a python script with arguments from another python script without using import

Tags: python, import, arguments, exec, python-3.7

I want to run a python script (`test2_main.py`) with arguments from another python script (`test1_src.py`) without using `import` module.

One method that I found in `python3` was using the `exec` command. It runs fine for me if no arguments are passed to the `test2_main.py` script. Dummy code is shown below:

For example:

First script (outer) is `test1_src.py`:

```
bash-4.2$ cat test1_src.py
exec(open("test2_main.py").read())
```

Second script (inner) is `test2_main.py`:

```
bash-4.2$ cat test2_main.py
print("Inside test2_main.py script.. \n")
```

Output when running the outer script `test1_src.py`

```
bash-4.2$ /usr/local/bin/python3.7 test1_src.py 
Inside test2_main.py script..
```

Now, if I have to pass two arguments to the `test2_main.py` script, how can I achieve that?

For example, I want something like this:

outer script (`test1_src.py`) is below. In this the inner script `test2_main.py` accepts two arguments `cat` and `bat`:

```
bash-4.2$ cat test1_src.py
exec(open("test2_main.py" "cat" "bat").read())
```

Inner script `test2_main.py`:

```
bash-4.2$ cat test2_main.py
print("Inside test2_main.py script.. \n")

input1 = sys.argv[1]
input2 = sys.argv[2]

print(" input args to this script are"  + input1 + "and " + input2)
```

Desired output is:

```
bash-4.2$ /usr/local/bin/python3.7 test1_src.py 
Inside test2_main.py script.. 

input args to this script are cat and bat
```

This code doesn't work. I want to understand from the community how can I run `test2_main.py` with arguments `cat` and `bat` within `test1_src.py` script.

I know it can work using the `import` module but I don't want to use it. Reason being that I want to run the whole script instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this, if this can help you**

```
import os
os.system("python test2_main.py args &")
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test2_main.py', 'args'])
```

Comment: Thanks Ankush. os.system works for me.

Comment: Welcome, You can upvote me and approve this answer
Thanks